# How to best get a byte array from C# to a C++ WinRT component

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime

We have a WinRT component with business logic that internally massages a C++ `unsigned char` buffer. We now want to feed that buffer from a C# `byte[]`. What would the perfect boundary look like, *i.e.*, what would the signature of the `SomeWinRTFunction` function below be?

```
void SomeWinRTFunction(something containing bytes from managed land)
{
    IVector<unsigned char> something using the bytes given from managed land;
}
```

This kind of issue seems too new still for search engines to find it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the C++ part, the method should accept a platform array of uint8 (the equivalent of C# byte).

```
public ref class Class1 sealed
{
public:
    Class1();
    //readonly array
    void TestArray(const Platform::Array<uint8>^ intArray)
    {

    }
    //writeonly array
    void TestOutArray(Platform::WriteOnlyArray<uint8>^ intOutArray)
    {

    }

};
```

In the C# part pass the byte array:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Byte[] b = new Byte[2];
        b[0] = 1;
        var c = new Class1();
        c.TestArray(b);
        c.TestOutArray(b); 

    }
```

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755822(v=vs.110).aspx *"C++/CX also defines uint8, equivalent to unsigned char, which is not supported in the Windows Runtime and cannot be used in public APIs"* - so I guess `uchar` would be more "correct"?

Comment: True, but since this API will be consumed by other language(s) you need a supported type as part of the public API (UInt8). The other point I was trying to make that arrays are actually supported so no need to use generic collections unless you want to.

Comment: I don't understand this: *"... since this API will be consumed by other language(s) you need a supported type as part of the public API (UInt8) ..."* - the provided link says `uint8` **cannot** be used in public APIs and you say that it *is* supported in a public API.

Comment: Also: *"... The other point I was trying to make that arrays are actually supported so no need to use generic collections unless you want to... "* - that's a good point!

Comment: Which link says that uint8 can not be used in the public API? If you take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700121(v=vs.110).aspx you see that uint8 is part of the supported API (C++/CX) and the corresponding type in standard C++ is unsigned char. The code I included in my answer runs successfully on Win8 RC.

Comment: *"Which link says that uint8 can not be used in the public API?"* - I quoted that in my first comment. The quote is verbatim copied from that link. It says *"... not supported in the Windows Runtime and cannot be used in public APIs."*

Comment: I think what you quoted is for unsigned char not UInt8, I agree the way it's written is confusing and I will be following up on that.

Comment: Aha, I see now that you're a colleague ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In WinRT IVector is projected as IList, i'm not sure about byte -> unsigned char but i suspect is too.

C#

```
byte[] array;
SomeWinRTFunction(array);
```

C++

```
void SomeWinRTFunction(IVector<unsigned char> bytes) 
{ 
    IVector<unsigned char> something using the bytes given from managed land; 
}
```

This [whitepaper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/3/E/23E1E9BE-41AA-4716-A7B3-82040271394C/CLRandtheWindowsRuntime.docx) might shed some more light.